# Magento : Remove a total on 1 store

Tags: php, magento

I have a Magento installation with 3 stores.

I added a custom total on one of these stores 3 monthes ago, everything was working fine.

I just update to the last version 1.7.0.2 and now I have a problem on my B2B store. In this particular store this total is not used (always set to 0) and in this store all prices are excluding tax.

Since I'm using the 1.7.0.2 Magento CE version orders are place excluding tax and no tax are calculated, except if I desactivate the module for this additionnal total.

I found a solution to deactivate the module only in this store, and that is working fine on frontend (total used in the right store and not used in the B2B store) but when I try ordering from the backend I have problems. If I allow my module in backend order for the B2B store have no tax, if I don't allow it orders for the good store don't have this additionnal total.

If someone could help me for removing this total in this store I will really appreciate.

Best Regards,

Comment: Have you tried creating a tax rule ? I think that may work for you.

Comment: A tax rule for what ? For handling my additionnal total ?
Just before moving to CE 1.7.0.2 it was working fine, I had 1 site with additionnal total 'payment_charge' when you choose 1 typical payment method, this total is taxed so you had :

Item => $100 Incl Tax
Shipping $30 Incl Tax
Payment Charge 5% => 130*0.05 => $6.5 Incl Tax

Total => $136.5 Incl Tax with $22.7 Tax (19.6%)

Now this is still working but on another website with no payment charge there is no Tax anymore (when collecting this $0 total it put back tax to 0 Oo...